# How can I turn 10 similar event methods into a single one to work for said 10 events?

Tags: c#, winforms

I apologize if I was unable to word my question correctly, I'm not sure if there's a name for what I'm looking for.

I have the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> captions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

And some method like this:

```
public string disallowChar(string input)
    {
        if (input.Contains(@"|") || input.Contains(@"\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You may not enter the characters | or \\.");
            input = "";
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Finally, I have this "Validation" code for 10 different textboxes all named 'caption1', 'caption2' ... 'caption10' (With the EventHandlers in the winforms designer script):

```
private void caption1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captions[1] = disallowChar(caption1.Text);
        caption1.Text = captions[1];
    }

    private void caption2_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captions[2] = disallowChar(caption2.Text);
        caption2.Text = captions[2];
    }

    //.
    //.
    //Skip unnecessarily pasted methods 3-9 (Point made)
    //.
    //.

    private void caption10_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captions[10] = disallowChar(caption10.Text);
        caption10.Text = captions[10];
    }
```

This code works fine. And since my little program has plenty of inputs I have a similar "way of doing it" for everything else like buttons, numericaUpDowns, etc.
However, even as a beginner I know this isn't the correct way to do it. By doing this I have over 1000 lines, when maybe I should have 100.
I know I that I could go to the "Events Properties" and set the 'Validated' property to a single Validation method for each textbox. I just don't know what method would work to encompass all.

Unfortunately I just don't know what I'm searching for to do this. I looked up the "this" property, but can't understand how it could help withing a bunch of classes. Otherwise my searches run dry.

Assuming I set a 1-10 integer for each textbox somehow (let's call it `keyValue`) I imagine a solution that looks like the following where when I put the `this.Text` or `this.keyValue` where the keyword `this` "magically" references the textbox involved (However when i attempt the `this.Text` approach anywhere in my program, it returns my program's window name):

```
private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captions[this.keyValue] = disallowChar(this.Text);
        this.Text = captions[this.keyValue];
    }
```

Is there an alternative to the `this` keyword for this to work? Or am I misunderstanding how to use it?

**Edit with Answer:** I'm a newby, but as I've searched and used this site a lot I always like when Users edit their questions with their final solutions. Thanks to the accepted answer I've used this:

```
private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        int keyValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Tag);
        captions[keyValue] = disallowChar(textBox.Text);
        textBox.Text = captions[keyValue];
    }
```

Where with the winforms Designer I set the "Tag" property for each caption textBox to its respective number.
The `(int)textBox.Tag` was giving an error. After googling a bit I found that "`Tag` is inherited from the `Control` class and is `System.Object` type." and a suggestion to use the `Convert` class and it worked.

Using a Dictionary and how I'm validating strings may be inefficient, but this sure is better and has enlightened me a lot on the `object sender` and `Tag` parts. Hope this may one day help someone else. Thanks.

Comment: what is the key value?

Comment: @NoOne the key values are for the dictionary are are integers 1-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest fix I can think of:

Use the `sender` parameter, and put integer into `Tag` property of each caption:

```
//...
caption1.Tag = 0;
caption2.Tag = 1;
//...
```

- you can do it in the designer when creating the TextBoxes (`Tag` property in the properties of the control)
- or if the captions are somehow generated in the code, then it should be easy to assign their Tags automatically

Then:

```
private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    captions[(int)textBox.Tag] = disallowChar(textBox.Text);
    textBox.Text = captions[(int)textBox.Tag];
}
```

But anyway, I'm not sure why do you need `captions` dictionary - seems redundant, as all the captions are stored in `Text` property of each TextBox.

Comment: Actually you can use textbox name as captions key. Just use `<string, string>` dictionary

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this now. This is my first posting and i'm amazed at the reply speed! Hope I asked correctly. As for using a dictionary I have it as basically the only working fallback for all the Array Out of Bounds errors I was getting. There are also 2 other dictionaries with the same keys, I sort one of them and line the other's up with it. I'm used to javascript where I could put `var array=[{'Image':"1.jpg", 'Caption':"hiya", 'Page': 4},{'Image':"8.jpg", 'Caption':"bye", 'Page': 9}];` then organize and use. In C# I couldn't find anything similar :(

Comment: @BartoszKP It worked! (Sort of) See my Edit for the simple alteration of `(int)` to `Convert.ToInt32()` to avoid some exception error I was getting. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

Assign your keyvalues to tags of your textboxes

Register all your textboxes to this event.

```
private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    int key = (int)textBox.Tag;
    string result = disallowChar(textBox.Text);
    captions[key] = result;
    textBox.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `sender` parameter will contain the `object` that generated the event, which is what enables you to have one event handler with general logic for multiple `TextBox`es.  I suspect this is what @JustSomeHobbyist meant when they were trying to use `this`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<int, string> captions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Does the key required to be `int` here ?
If yes then try @BartoszKP 's solution. else try this

```
Dictionary<TextBox, string> captions = new Dictionary<TextBox, string>();
```

store the actual textboxes in dictionary

```
private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Text = captions[textBox] = disallowChar(textBox.Text);
}
```

Or.. How about this?

```
Dictionary<string, string> captions = new Dictionary<string, string>();//use textbox names as key

private void caption_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Text = captions[textBox.Name] = disallowChar(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Sriram, this looks like a solid answer. Love the alternatives. I went with BartoszKP's solution since I organize 3 dictionaries side-by-side with the same set of integer Keys. I'd upVote if I had 15 rep lol, i'll be back... Thanks!